# Can't perform a PHP POST request on mysql database

Tags: php, api, rest, post

I'm struggling into do my first API in php and I'm facing some problems with a simple POST request. I've searched almost everywhere for some alternatives to my code, but it seems to be ok. Can you guys check it for me the last time? Thank you!

method:

```
function create_msg(){

    // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                msg_key=:msg_key, msg_id=:msg_id, msg_author=:msg_author, msg_txt=:msg_txt";
  
    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
  
    // sanitize
    $this->msg_key=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->msg_key));
    $this->msg_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->msg_id));
    $this->msg_author=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->msg_author));
    $this->msg_txt=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->msg_txt));
  
    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":msg_key", $this->msg_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(":msg_id", $this->msg_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":msg_author", $this->msg_author);
    $stmt->bindParam(":msg_txt", $this->msg_txt);

  
    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }
  
    return false;
      
}
```

create.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../models/msg.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$item = new msg($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$item->msg_key = $data->msg_key;
$item->msg_id = $data->msg_id;
$item->msg_author = $data->msg_author;
$item->msg_txt = $data->msg_txt;
var_dump($data);

if($item->create_msg()){
    echo 'OK';
} else{
    echo 'Not OK';
}
?>
```

Comment: Does `var_dump($data);` show the expected result?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the documentation to see what `htmlspecialchars()` and `strip_tags()` actually do. Hint: it's absolutely nothing to do with databases.

Comment: @miken32 every website even here in stack use htmlspecialchars() to sanitize data and strip_tags() to remove any html tags

Comment: @Barmar actually yes, it seems to be full of the informations. `object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
    [
        "msg_key"
    ]=>
  string(9) "123456789"
  [
        "msg_id"
    ]=>
  string(6) "A00006"
  [
        "msg_author"
    ]=>
  string(6) "sandro"
  [
        "msg_txt"
    ]=>
  string(3) "lol"
}`

Comment: Where do you set `$item->table_name`?

Comment: @Barmar actually I didn't put it anywhere. Where do I have to put it?

Comment: Somewhere between `$item = new msg($db);` and `$item->create_msg()`. How else is it supposed to be set?

Comment: @Barmar ok, so I put `$item->$table_name` right before `$item->create_msg()` where $table_name is linked to the method (the first box, I changed it from 'private' to 'public')

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You need to do sometjhing like `$item->table_name = "message_table";`, replacing `message_table` with the actual name of the table you want to insert into.

Comment: @Barmar `$item->table_name = "message_table";` don't resolve $item->table_name = "msg_table";
    `if($item->create_msg()){
        echo 'OK';
    } else{
        echo 'Not OK';
    }` output: Not OK

Comment: Enable `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` so that you get an error if there's a problem with your query, instead of just reporting `Not OK`

Comment: it gave me "2".

Comment: @Barmar ok, so the problem is an :ATTR_ERRMODE:

Comment: No, that's a way to get the debugging information.

Comment: What do you mean by "It gave me 2"? YOu're not supposed to print it, you're supposed to enable that option. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: ok, only` PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` gave me `2`, but with `echo $current_error_mode;` it outputs `:ATTR_ERRMODE:`

Comment: `$db->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @Barmar ok, so it's a "Value of PDO: :ATTR_ERRMODE: Connection failed: invalid data source name"

Comment: So there's a problem in either `config/database.php` or the `Database` class.

Comment: @Barmar well, I think the database.php host, user, database name and password is ok, in the class database there's nothing other than the connection and a PDO exception
 `public function getConnection()
  {
  $this->conn = null;
  try
   {
   $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
   $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
   }
  catch(PDOException $exception)
   {
   echo "Errore di connessione: " . $exception->getMessage();
   }
  return $this->conn;`

Comment: sorry for the bad indentation

Comment: Are `$this->host` and `this->db_name` correctly set?

Comment: Code in comments can't be formatted. If it's more than just one line you should post in the question.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: yes, host and db_name are correctly setted

Comment: That error message means there's a problem with the DSN used with `new PDO()`. I don't know what to tell you. Google the error message and you'll find other questions showing how to fix it.

Comment: ok thx man for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I managed to resolve with this code in the config/database.php

```
<?php
class Database{
    private $host = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_touchy';
    private $username = 'touchy';
    private $password = '';


    public function getConnection() {
        $conn = new PDO($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE );
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

?>